# Moving apps to SD Card on Samsung Galaxy S20 FE Android 12

Tags: external-sd, app2sd, adoptable-storage, link2sd, samsung-galaxy-s-20

I purchased 6 months before, Samsung Galaxy s20 Fe with android  12 with 128 GB internal memory and a 256 GB external Micro SD card. I am an IT freelancer professional, so I have a job is for testing 1000's of different apps, and my main work is to install some video photo editing and some technical official apps to do my job in an instant go while traveling.

In Android 12.0 of Samsung Galaxy S20 Fe There is an option of CHANGE option in Settings > App> Storage to change (move) location of app from internal to SD card in Android.

[image: Screenshot of change moving location]

But its the same like as in Android 5.0, it only moves the main APK files, leaving data, cache, lib, and dex in internal memory thus occupying space in internal memory. I want to keep my internal memory free for output files of video editing to fast rendering of photo editing or video editing file on mobile.

MY QUERIES:-

1. Is there any option without rooting to move the complete apps (lib, dex, data, and cache) to an external micro SD card?

[image: apk files]

2. There was an option in Android 6.0 Marshmallow for adaptable storage to format an external SD card as internal memory and move complete application files. Can I do that in Android 12.0?

[image: Screenshot format as internal]

3. there any developer option in Android 12.0 to force or make default installation of apps in the external memory card so that all apps are installed automatically with apk,lib, dex,data file in the external memory card but it works with only 5 to 10 apps out of 100 it still leave some part in internal memory?

[image: Screenshot Force install to sd]

4. In Android 6.0, I tried to edit the app manifest through the APK editor to change the default install location of an app to external memory. Will it work in Android 12.0? But it's time-consuming to edit every application.

[image: Apk editor app manifest]

5. Can we root Samsung Galaxy S20 FE and use the Link2SD app or any script in boot.int or any other new application in Android 12.0 which with its script links all lib, dex files in a micro SD card?

[image: link2sd internal data]

6. Is there any other way or method or settings options  in developer options or any other 3rd part application in Android 12.0 Samsung Galaxy S20 FE so that I can move (dex lib apk data)  or install complete application directly to external micro SD card and  keep my internal memory free for working or output files rendering ?

The reason why I still want to move apps to sd Card while having internal memory of 128GB is for testing 1000's apps and editing and rendering short video and photo editing .

I know External micro sd card is slower than internal memory but the app I install for TESTING   on external memory will be rarely used may  2 or 3 times a year but for testing and reporting to companies i need to keep it  installed in mobile for year to give usage or some log reports and its useless to give them space in internal memory and make them full my internal memory  i cant uninstall or re-install them .

Comment: For app testing I would never use a phone that I use for business and thus that is important to me.

Comment: @Robert I have three phones samsung s20fe i use for working  app testing and video editing photo editing .. second one Samsung galaxy f22 i use for banking and secure works  ..... Samsung galaxy f62 third one i use for calling  and social needs.... but for apps and unsecure work and editing working  i use samsung s20 fe  mobile as no risk for data stolen... and samsung galaxy s20 fe good for video photo rendering and many  have 8gb RAm and Qualcomm SM8250 Snapdragon 865 5G CPU Octa-core (1x2.84 GHz Cortex-A77 & 3x2.42 GHz Cortex-A77 & 4x1.80 GHz Cortex-A55) GPU Adreno 650

Comment: 1-6) no 5) only on unlockable bootloader